# Where can I buy susceptor film?

Tags: microwave

This week I was introduced to "susceptor film" by some folks from Japan.  It's used for cooking things such as fish at high temperature in a microwave, by absorbing some of the microwave energy and re-emitting it as infrared (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susceptor).  The result is that microwaved food comes out crispy rather than soggy.

I was told that it's commonly available in Japanese supermarkets, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere online, or in my local supermarket in the western USA.

The closest I've come is finding [a manufacturer](http://www.sirane.com/microwave-susceptors-crisp-it-range/sira-crisp-crisp-it-susceptor-films.html) and some [cooking bags](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004OF968O) on Amazon.  Any clues?

Comment: I know this post is ancient, but I decided to do some googling. googling "susceptor film" got me a second manufacturer, https://www.sirane.com/en/product/sira-crisp-susceptor-films/ , with a proprietary name "sira-crisp" (seems to be wholesale-only, sold to packaging manufacturers or something). googling "sira-crisp" and going to the "shopping" tab got me the brand name "MicroCrisp," which apparently is a brand of susceptor products from the 90's. You can find old (sometimes used) products under that brand name on Amazon and Ebay.

Comment: Also [this product](https://buyhomegadgets.com/products/brown-and-crisp-microwave-cooking-bags?variant=31490379153526&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic), which doesn't seem old/used

Comment: Thanks for the hints!  It's funny how life goes... I actually ended up spending three months in Japan a year after I posted this.  I searched all the supermarkets and came up with nothing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The magic words appear to be "crisping" or "crisper".  Searches for "microwave crisping sheet" or "microwave crisper sleeve" turn up a number of products that can be purchased.

Or you can always buy some Hot Pockets and keep the sleeves after you eat the food. :-)

Comment: But then I might have to *eat* those Hot Pockets! :P